# Import Mako template in Django Template file

Tags: django, templates, mako

I have `base.html` which is written in `Django Template Engine` and I want to import a mako file `footer.html`.

Is it possible to import mako template in django?
How I can import it?

Comment: Why a vote down? Would you like to explain? No comment, no reference for solution, thats harsh.

Answer (score -2):

How about this?

```
<!-- base.html --!>

...

<body>

{% include 'footer.html' %}

</body>
```

```
<!-- footer --!>

{% extends 'base.html' %}

...
```